# unable to GET data from bing api

Tags: ruby, api, sinatra

I am trying to post coordinates for origin and destination to bing api for getting directions. But I am unable to send the data.

```
 def get_info_from_bing(params)
    base_url="http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Routes/"
    query_params = "?" + {
            "wayPoint.1" => params[:origin],
            "waypoint.2" => params[:destination],
            "dateTime" => params[:time] || Time.now.strftime("%H:%M"),
            "timeType" => "Arrival",
            "key" => ENV['BING_KEY']
    }.map {|k,v| "#{k}=#{CGI.escape(v)}"}*"&"
    modes=%w{driving walking transit}
```

Error:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass:
/Users/anirvan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/lib/ruby/1.9.1/cgi/util.rb:7:in `escape'
/Users/anirvan/codeforamerica-transpochoices-1ccac48/choices.rb:15:in `block in get_info_from_bing'
/Users/anirvan/codeforamerica-transpochoices-1ccac48/choices.rb:15:in `each'
/Users/anirvan/codeforamerica-transpochoices-1ccac48/choices.rb:15:in `map'
/Users/anirvan/codeforamerica-transpochoices-1ccac48/choices.rb:15:in `get_info_from_bing'
/Users/anirvan/codeforamerica-transpochoices-1ccac48/choices.rb:120:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/anirvan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1212:in `call'
/Users/anirvan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1212:in `block in compile!'
/Users/anirvan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:772:in `[]'
/Users/anirvan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:772:in `block (3 levels) in route!'
```

I am new to sinatra and ruby. Does anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `params.inspect` to print the content of your `param` array. One of the values is certainly `nil`, that why `CGI.escape(v)` throws an exception.

If you can fix the `nil` value, use the following line as a workaround:

```
...
}.map {|k,v| "#{k}=#{CGI.escape(v||'')}"}*"&"
...
```